# Wordpress use array key and value to set data attribute

Tags: arrays, wordpress, key

I have setup an array of product values. I need to set each array key to the data-attribute and the value to the data-attribute value

`<li data-name="product1" data-price="49.99" data-rating="4.5"></li>`

So in Wordpress I have this filter hook

```
function product_data_sorting( $product_attrs, $product, $terms) {
    global $post;

    // Product Attributes
    $product_attrs['name']  = $post->post_name;
    $product_attrs['price']     = $product->price;
    $product_attrs['rating']    = $product->get_average_rating();
    $product_attrs['newness']   = $post->post_modified;

    // Product Categories
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $categories[]  = $term->slug;
    }
    $product_attrs['categories'] = $categories;


    foreach ($product_attrs as $attribute) {
        if ( is_array($attribute) ) {
            //This is a category
        }
        else {
            $results[] = 'data-' . $key . '="' . '$attribute' . '"';
        }   
    }
    return $results
}
add_filter( 'add_sorting', 'product_data_sorting', 10, 3 );
```

I am getting all the correct data pushed in to the $product_attrs array that I need, but not sure how to work with the array key and values so that in the $results array it would be formatted like this:

`$results = (data-name="product1", data-price="49.99", data-rating="4.5");`

Hope that makes some sense

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need `key=>value` pair within `foreach`.

```
$ignored = array ('newness'); // array to maintain what attributes you want to ignore

     foreach ($product_attrs as $key => $attribute) {
            if ( is_array($attribute) ) {
                //This is a category
            }
            else {
               if(!inarray($key, $ignored) 
                  $results[] = 'data-' . $key . '="' . $attribute . '"';
            }   
     }
```

*Also note that $attribute isn't enlcosed in single quotes as you have in the question. Variables inside single quote can not be parsed*